# How to include date+time when directing systemd StandardOutput to a file

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service that outputs to a log file with

```
StandardOutput=file:/path/to/log/file
StandardError=file:/path/to/error/file
```

How can I prepend these outputs and errors with data+time so that it reads

```
10-09-2019 12:43:23 The output here.
```

Comment: Your desired output looks like from `journalctl`. You can add .conf file in `/etc` where you can change stdout and sterr to journal. e.g. `StandardError=journal`.

Comment: @Biswapriyo The logs need to be in the files indicated rather than the journal.

Comment: I'm surprised this question doesn't receive more attention, it's the first one showing up when searching on the web for this. There doesn't seem to be any easy way to do as of the latest systemd release (v.250) which is very surprising.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (warning: untested)

1. `Enable` and `Start` a "logging.service" with `systemctl`
2. In the `[Service]` definition of `logging.service` use the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start logging server   # or whatever you choose to call it

[Service]
...
Type=forking
ExecStart=/bin/bash myLogger.sh start
...
```

3. Write the `bash` script `myLogger.sh` (or whatever you call it). In the script, use the following to begin each line in the log:

```
printf '%(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T' -1
```

`printf` doesn't introduce a newline character, so you should be able to append your log data immediately after that.

Comment: This is incomplete, this doesn't interact with OP's service per itself.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do it with `StandartOutput` and `StandardError` from systemd but got a workaround for my python3 scripts running with systemd. Since journald by default also sends its output to syslog, you can work with rsyslog (or whatever syslog utility you have on your system) to achieve what you want (although the output will also be duplicated in journald, like everything journald related when sending to syslog is enabled (default config on most modern distros)).

Here is my `/etc/rsyslog.d/python3_custom.conf` configuration file:

```
template(name="python3_custom_file" type="string" string="/var/log/python3/%programname:16:$%/out.log")
template(name="python3_custom_output" type="list") {
     property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
     constant(value=" ")
     property(name="syslogseverity-text" caseConversion="upper")
     property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on")
     property(name="msg" droplastlf="on")
     constant(value="\n")
}

if($programname startswith 'python3_custom_') then {
        action(type="omfile" dynaFile="python3_custom_file" template="python3_custom_output")
        stop
}
```

Then you `systemctl restart rsyslog`. Finally, you need to tell your systemd service which syslog `programname` to use, you can do that by adding the `SyslogIdentifier=python3_custom_programname` directive to your `.service` file. This way you can have multiple services and just change `programname` at the end of that directive to have it output into `/var/log/python3/programname/out.log` (which you can easily change to your liking).